# How to draw directly to LinearLayout's canvas - Android

Tags: android-layout, android-canvas

I have a LinearLayout with 3 ImageView s on it. Whenever the user clicks on an ImageView I want to draw a surrounding rectangle on the ImageView. I know how to draw something on a ImageView but I want to draw directly on the LinearLayout.

How can I do this?
I've already written the following code:

`setContentView(R.id.anaekran2);
LinearLayout linLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout01);`

Is there something like `linLayout.getCanvas()`? 
I couldn't find a similiar function, but I've found
`linLayout.getDrawingCache()`. So,

`Bitmap b = linLayout.getDrawingCache();
Canvas c = new Canvas(b); // this line gives an error, why?`

Comment: What is the error? And is the drawing cache enabled?

Comment: I forgot to check the "b" value. It's null! But it's null even if call linLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true); before I call linLayout.getDrawingCache();  Is it possible to draw directly to a LinearLayout?

Answer (score 1):

You should create a custom linear layout. Overriding onDraw method of linear layout solves your problem. Here is the custom linear layout code.

```
public class CustomLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {

private Paint mPaint;
private int mClickedChild = -1;

public CustomLinearLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setWillNotDraw(false);
    createPaint();
}

public CustomLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setWillNotDraw(false);
    createPaint();
}

public CustomLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    setWillNotDraw(false);
    createPaint();
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
    initializeChildrenClickEvent();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    if(mClickedChild != -1){
        View child = getChildAt(mClickedChild);
        canvas.drawRect(child.getLeft(), child.getTop(), child.getRight(), child.getBottom(), mPaint);
    }
}

private void initializeChildrenClickEvent(){
    final int childCount = getChildCount();
    OnClickListener clickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            for(int i = 0; i < childCount; i++){
                if(getChildAt(i).equals(view)){
                    mClickedChild = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            invalidate();
        }
    };

    for(int i = 0; i < childCount; i++){
        getChildAt(i).setOnClickListener(clickListener);
    }
}

private void createPaint(){
    mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(5f);
}
}
```

And here is the usage of custom layout in xml.

```
<CustomLinearLayout      
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_view_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_view_2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_view_3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</CustomLinearLayout>
```

Comment: If I dynamically add the child to the LinearLayout, and when the child is selected, draw a view on the child, how should I do?

Comment: In that case, you must remove the click listener from children and add touch listener to custom layout. Depending on touch position, you can identify the clicked child.

Comment: I have solved my problem by using dispathDraw method, because the onDraw method will draw my view under the children.